# Showing that $\mathbb{R}_k$ and $\mathbb{R}_l$ are not comparable

Tags: general-topology

The topology $\mathbb{R}_k$ is defined as:

Let $K$ be the set $\{\frac{1}{n}, n\in \mathbb{Z}_+\}$. Then the topology $\mathbb{R}_k$ is generated by the basis elements of the form $(a,b)$ and $(a,b)-K$.

The topology $\mathbb{R}_l$ is the one of the lower topology, that is, the one generated by $[a,b)$

It's easy to see that every basis element of $\mathbb{R}$ is contained in $\mathbb{R}_k$, but for the converse, that's what I did:

Let $(-1,1)-K$ be a basis element on $\mathbb{R}_k$ that contains $x$

then there's no basis element of $\mathbb{R}$ that contains $x$ and $(-1,1)-K$.
I can see this intuitively, but can I say for example that this wouldn't be possible since if we pick $x=0$, then there are infinitely points next to $0$ and thus there is no way that $(a,b)$ in $\mathbb{R}$ contains this set?

Comment: What's $\Bbb{R}_l$ (in the title)? Also the interval $(1, 1)$ is empty so the first line of "what I did' doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Sorry, it's the lower topology, generated by $[a,b)$. Also, why empty?

Comment: ooooooooops, sorry, I meant $(-1,1)-K$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $\mathbb R$ is finer than the K topology, then there exists $(a,b)$ so that $ 0 \in (a,b) \subset (-1,1) \setminus K$, then $b>0$ so $b > \frac{1}{n} >0$ which is a contradiction (why?)

Also, for $\mathbb R_{l}$ is not finer than $\mathbb R_{k}$, since for $(-1,1) \setminus K$ and $0$, there is no $[a,b)$ so that $0 \in [a,b) \subset (-1,1) \setminus K$, similarly for the other way.